# Right way to collect batch normalization statistics in multiple GPUs scenario?

Tags: tensorflow

I am training the BatchNorm layer in multiple GPUs using `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` function. In the training phase, we have to collect moving_mean and moving_variance using the function

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
```

However, I found that utilization of the function has some ways

1.**Inside a loop function** [cifar10_main](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10_estimator/cifar10_main.py#L121)

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  update_ops=[]
  with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
     for i in range(self.conf.num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
       with tf.name_scope('device_%d' % i):
          update_ops.extend(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))
  variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(self.conf.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)
  variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
  with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
     self.train_op = tf.group(train_op_conv,variables_averages_op)
```

2.**Outside a loop function** [cifar10_multi_gpu](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py)

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
     for i in range(self.conf.num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
       with tf.name_scope('device_%d' % i):
          #Igore the line update_ops
  variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(self.conf.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)
  variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
  update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)  
  with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
     self.train_op = tf.group(train_op_conv,variables_averages_op)
```

3.**Both inside and outside a loop function** [inception v3](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/inception_train.py), [cifar10](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/dd9a81c03bf924db8d461a3e696ba1bd4bb193fc/tutorials/image/cifar10_estimator/cifar10_main.py)

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
     for i in range(self.conf.num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
       with tf.name_scope('device_%d' % i):
          update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS) 
  variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(self.conf.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)
  variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())            
  batchnorm_updates_op = tf.group(*update_ops)
  self.train_op = tf.group(train_op_conv, train_op_fc,variables_averages_op,batchnorm_updates_op)
```

What is the right way? In my opinion, it may be the second way

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you provided for the first approach does not match the cifar_10 example. The approach taken in the [cifar10_main](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10_estimator/cifar10_main.py#L121-L122) example collects and applies only those update ops that originate from the first tower, as a heuristic code optimization. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
  with tf.variable_scope('resnet', reuse=bool(i != 0)):
    with tf.name_scope('tower_%d' % i) as name_scope:
      with tf.device(device_setter):
        loss, gradvars, preds = _tower_fn(
            is_training, weight_decay, tower_features[i], tower_labels[i],
            data_format, params.num_layers, params.batch_norm_decay,
            params.batch_norm_epsilon)
        tower_losses.append(loss)
        tower_gradvars.append(gradvars)
        tower_preds.append(preds)
        if i == 0:
          # Only trigger batch_norm moving mean and variance update from
          # the 1st tower. Ideally, we should grab the updates from all
          # towers but these stats accumulate extremely fast so we can
          # ignore the other stats from the other towers without
          # significant detriment.
          update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS,
                                         name_scope)
```

Note that in the above snippet, the update ops are restricted to those originating from the first tower via the `name_scope` that is passed as an argument to `tf.get_collection`.

The second approach applies all update ops, across all towers.

The third approach, as you have written it, is a variant of the first approach. However, the linked-to inceptionv3 file in fact does something similar to the cifar10_main example.

With respect to which approach is the *right* approach: it depends. Selectively applying update ops may decrease the time per training step while sacrificing (some definition of) correctness, whereas applying all update ops may increase the time per training step. In practice, try both and see which trade-off suits you better.

Comment: Thanks for a clear explaination. So, I just summarize your question as : method 1: BN parameters only get from first tower. Method 2 AND method 3: BN prams are computed from BN params of all tower. I am working in segmentation, thus large Batch size will be useful. Which method (2 or 3) can use to update final BN parameters from all towers ? It means that the final BN params are computed from average moving mean and variance of all towers

Comment: If you want to collect the update ops for all towers, then the second method should work.